# How to export runnable JAR with Eclipse and exclude .svn directories?

Tags: eclipse, svn, export, executable-jar

I want to create a **runnable Jar** using Eclipse export tools.

However, when I export my project, Eclipse includes .svn directories in the Runnable jar.

I try to exclude these directories using Eclipse properties without success (using `**/.svn/*` in the source excluded file ; I also try other combinations like `**/.svn`, `**/.svn/`, `.svn`, etc...).

Does anyone know if it is possible to do that or should I manually delete the .svn directories from the executable JAR?

Answer (score 0):

You can pass to the recent >1.7 working copy format (update your svn clients). It make no more use of .svn directories, so you won't have the problem anymore.

If you use external clients (such as TortoiseSVN) you must conform your plugins for svn in Eclipse (subclipse, etc.) to >1.7 version too.

The new working copy version does not work with older ones (they must be converted),

If you use a Maven build to build your jar, the .svn directories (among others tipical SCM systems control directories) are excluded by default behaviour; see in particular the [maven archiver plugin configuration to have an executable jar](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/classpath.html#aMake).